# Не правильно срабатывает function js

Tags: javascript, html

подскажите пожалуйста
В игре есть достижение, которое срабатывает когда пользователь сделает 100 кликов.
После нажатия на достижение чтобы забрать наград присваивается True по умолчанию False

```
let bonusReceived = localStorage.getItem('bonusReceived') || false;
```

Когда присваивается True срабатывает скрипт и Самому блоку присваивается display="none" а к блоку об успешном выполнении достижения присваивается display="block"

Данная система работает. Но сейчас я работаю над сохранением данных с помощью localStorage
Но получается так что когда новый пользователь заходит в игру у него по умолчанию False с этим проблем нет.

```
let bonusReceived = localStorage.getItem('bonusReceived') || false;
```

Но в разделе достижения где находится сама кнопка, срабатывает система которая должна сработать когда у пользователя будет True

```
let bonusReceived = localStorage.getItem('bonusReceived') || true;
```

КОД

```
let bonusReceived = localStorage.getItem('bonusReceived') || false; 

insertTextBR(bonusReceived);

function insertTextBR(bonusReceived) {
    let advancesButtonNone = document.getElementById("testdisplaynone");
    if (bonusReceived = localStorage.getItem('bonusReceived') || true) {
        advancesButtonNone.style.display  = "none";
    }
    let advancesButtonNone2 = document.getElementById("testdisplaynone_2");
    if (bonusReceived = localStorage.getItem('bonusReceived') || true) {
        advancesButtonNone2.style.display  = "block";
    }
}

function updateStorageBN(bonusReceived) {
    localStorage.setItem('bonusReceived', bonusReceived);
}

const advancesOne = () => {

    if (countclicks >= needClicksForBonus && bonusReceived === false) {
        advances_bl += 200;
        balance_bnb += 0.1;
        bonusReceived = true;
        document.getElementById('balance_bnb').innerText = balance_bnb.toFixed(3);

        let advancesButtonNone = document.getElementById("testdisplaynone");
        if (bonusReceived = true) {
            advancesButtonNone.style.display  = "none";
        }

        let advancesButtonNone2 = document.getElementById("testdisplaynone_2");
        if (bonusReceived = true) {
            advancesButtonNone2.style.display  = "block";
        }
    }

    let advancesButton = document.getElementById("advances_one_s");
    if (advances_bl <= 200) {
        advancesButton.style.opacity  = "0.4";
    }
}

document.getElementById('advances_one_s').addEventListener('click', advancesOne)
```

Comment: Старайтесь либо здесь использовать виджет для кода, чтоб можно выполнить Ваш код, либо заливайте на какой-нибудь хостинг, например на JSFiddle.net. Причина не может быть в том, что Вы пытаетесь сохранить в [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) булево значение? Согласно документации, все значения в LocalStorage являются строками. В условиях if не должно быть двух знаков равенства?

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, проблема была в самой простом месте, я использовал в if "||" а нужно было "&&"

Comment: Я всё равно не могу понять Ваш код: bonusReceived = true; и далее два условия if (bonusReceived = true) - зачем? Это будет всегда выполняться. Что происходит, если в локальном хранилище под ключом bonusReceived хранится строка 'false'? Вы тестировали такой случай?

Comment: У меня в разделе "Достижения" есть 2 div, одни div по умолчанию виден пользователю данный div по id=testdisplaynone. В testdisplaynone показывает сколько пользователю нужно сделать кликов что бы он  получил награду ну и конечно если на него нажать то начислит награду. Второй div под id=testdisplaynone_2 показывает что награду уже получена. По умолчанию стоит display=none. А теперь в чем заключается суть. Когда пользователь собирает награду, то в первом div testdisplaynone присваивается style="display:none" а ко второму style="display="block". И в bonusReceived значение с false меняется на True

Comment: Данное решение может не совсем правильное, но работает хорошо.
Не знаю конечно что будет если например сделать таких достижений 50, сильно ли повлияет это на нагрузку и повлияет ли вообще.